# How to uninstall an app from Gmail

Tags: gmail

Is it possible to uninstall an app that uses Google? I want something like the app settings in Facebook where you can edit or remove an app that you have previously installed:
[image]

So in Facebook all I have to do is to click the x button in there to uninstall the app.

How is this done in Google?

Comment: What kind of "app" are you trying to uninstall?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're asking how to revoke permissions to applications that use your Google authentication details.

To do this, click on "Manage Apps" in the "[Connected Apps & Sites](https://myaccount.google.com/security#connectedapps)" of your Google "[My Account](https://myaccount.google.com/)".

Once there click on "Remove" to the websites you wish to revoke.

[image: screen shot]