# Remove default apps from Gmail

Tags: google-launcher

Is it possible to remove some of the default Google apps from Gmail? I'm only using the Drive and the Calendar apps, and would like to remove the other apps (YouTube, Google+, Photos, etc). By remove, I mean either hide from view or delete them entirely.

I have followed the guide provided on the [official link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3466521?hl=en), and the answer provided [here on WA](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/51391/how-to-uninstall-an-app-from-gmail). However, these are about removing external apps. I would like to remove the ones by Google.

My reason for this is that the app view is too cluttered for me. More options is fine, but the way it's set up now is just... Annoying  to me.

The following image shows what I'd like to remove (or hide, if removal is impossible).

[image: remove from apps]

Comment: To confirm, you're just looking to remove these from the app selector, right? Because except for Google+ you can't "turn off" other Google features; you can only not use them.

Comment: Yes, I'd just like to remove them from the selector. They can still be usable in some way, but I don't want to see them in the selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the "App launcher" in the "Google bar", and it's visible in all Google apps. While you can move the icons around, you can't remove them.

If you open it up, you can drag-and-drop icons so they appear in the order you want them. You can drag them below the horizontal line so that they don't appear unless you click "More".

Unfortunately, there's no way to remove any of the existing icons; you can only move them around. You can [delete a few services from your 'My Account' page](https://myaccount.google.com/deleteservices) (notably Google+, YouTube, and Gmail) but that may not remove the icons from your launcher. (And they're not the apps you want to get rid of anyway.)

Resources:

- Google Support: [Use the Google bar](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1714464)
- Google Operating System: [Rearrange Apps in Google's Navigation Menu](https://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2014/03/rearrange-apps-in-googles-navigation.html)

Comment: Moving the apps around (and out of sight) does the trick. Strange that I didn't even think of click and dragging them around. Thanks!